# Error running - gem Install sass

Tags: 14.04, ruby

[Erro Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GYhk.png)

```
#gem install sass
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sass:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
/usr/bin/ruby2.2 -r ./siteconf20180217-38265-1l6kefu.rb extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... no
checking for ffi.h in /usr/local/include,/usr/include/ffi... no
checking for shlwapi.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_thread_call_with_gvl()... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl()... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
Running autoreconf for libffi
/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/ffi-1.9.21/ext/ffi_c/libffi/autogen.sh: 2: exec: autoreconf: not found
make: *** ["/var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/ffi-1.9.21/ext/ffi_c/libffi-x86_64-linux-gnu"/.libs/libffi_convenience.a] Error 127

make failed, exit code 2
```

Answer (score 2):

The Issue due to ruby-ffi package dependency and the ruby version,

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install ruby2.0 ruby2.0-dev
sudo apt-get install ruby-ffi

gem install sass
```